# Generar multiples resultados desde loop en python

Tags: python

> En este script puedo generar un resultado desde una lista de caracteres que se genera a tráves de un loop y este imprime una cadena de X cantidad

> lo que quiero es que imprima distintos resultados apartir desde que se generan la lista del string

> es decir que no imprima solamente un resultado sino que en un array se generen multiples contraseña ejemplo :

```
contrasenas = ['facebook', 'twiiter', 'instagram'];
```

```
 import random
def generar_contrasena():
    mayusculas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    minusculas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    simbolos = ['!', '#', '$', '&', '/', '(', ')']
    numeros = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

    caracteres = mayusculas + minusculas + simbolos + numeros

    contrasena = []

    for i in range(32):
        caracter_random = random.choice(caracteres)
        contrasena.append(caracter_random)
    contrasena = "".join(contrasena)
    return contrasena


def run():
    contrasena = generar_contrasena()
    print('Tu nueva contraseña es: ' + contrasena )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: No comprendo lo que quieres que haga. ¿Puedes explicarlo mejor?¿Cómo son de distintos los resultados esperados?

Comment: No queda nada claro qué quieres conseguir. El script ya genera una contraseña distinta cada vez que se ejecuta..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En verdad lo tienes practicamente hecho ya. Si quieres que genere múltiples contraseñas tan solo tienes que añadir un segundo bucle para que repita lo que ya tienes varias veces:

```
import random

def generar_contrasena():
    mayusculas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    minusculas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    simbolos = ['!', '#', '$', '&', '/', '(', ')']
    numeros = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

    caracteres = mayusculas + minusculas + simbolos + numeros

    contrasena = []

    # Añado un bucle más y tu bucle se queda dentro de este
    # Uso _ como nombre de variable para indicar que no se usará el valor
    for _ in range(3):
        # Declaro una variable donde iré almacenando la contraseña que genera el bucle interno
        passwd = ""
        for i in range(32):
            # He simplificado un poco tu lógica en este bucle, ahora passwd es 
            # un string así que no hay necesidad de usar join para unir la lista
            passwd += random.choice(caracteres)
        # Al salir del bucle interno, añado la contraseña generada
        contrasena.append(passwd)
    # Devuelvo el array de contraseñas
    return contrasena


def run():
    contrasena = generar_contrasena()
     # He eliminado el + para evitar la concatenación, cuando se pasan varios
     # parámetros a print, por defecto los imprime separándolos por espacios
    print('Tu nueva contraseña es:', contrasena )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado]
Puedes encontrar la explicación de los cambios en los comentarios, para cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Comment: def run():
    contrasena = generar_contrasena()
     # He eliminado el + para evitar la concatenación, cuando se pasan varios
     # parámetros a print, por defecto los imprime separándolos por espacios
    print('Tu nueva contraseña es:', contrasena )
//el print en esta función que devuelve la contraseña debo imprimirlo nuevamente o donde agrego el array ? en la variable contraseña antes de entrar al loop ?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta... eso imprime el array entero de contraseñas. He añadido una captura del resultado de ese print. Si buscas otra cosa, no lo he entendido así en tu pregunta, disculpa

Comment: como hago para agregar un salto a cada resultado o formatear el array ?

Comment: Si quieres añadir un salto a cada resultado, de la manera más sencilla, en vez de imprimir el array tal cual imprímelo dentro de un bucle uno a uno y ya está :)

Comment: lo otro seria tomar la posición de un array predefinido. para cada uno de los que se vaya imprimiendo